# is there any way to create a query in jpql for "list contains all in list"

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to create a query that returns the users that have all certifications in a list.

I have tried this :

```
public List<UserFilterModel> getUserBasedOnCertificationAndSkills(Filter filter)
{
    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder(
        "select  distinct user from UserEntity user left join fetch user.userCertifications uc where user.validity=true" 
   );
    if(!filter.getCertIds().isEmpty())
    {
        for(Integer id:filter.getCertIds())
            queryString.append(" and "+id+" in uc.certification.id");
    }...
```

But it is clearly not working. Strange thing is that if I change and operator with or it works fine.

Is there any other way I can do this like a `contains` in jpql

Comment: Define "not working". A JPA provider creates SQL. So look at the SQL created and work out why it "doesnt work"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want :

```
queryString.append(" and uc.certification.id = " +id);
```

Instead of :

```
queryString.append(" and "+id+" in uc.certification.id");
```